# Is Ice Climber limited to level 60?

Tags: diablo-iii

[Ice Climber](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ice-climbers) is a level 60 item. Is it limited to level 60 or does it also drop as a level 70 version? I found already three or four [Fire Walkers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/fire-walkers) but not Ice Climber at all. Fire Walker was originally a level 50 item but drops also as level 70 item. I am wondering if it is the same with Ice Climber? Does anybody have a level 70 Ice Climber?

Comment: yes they exist, I have 5 lvl 70 pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ice Climbers are not limited to level 60, they can and will drop at higher levels too. the level you can see on the battle.net website is the minimum level they can drop on.

So every single non-crafted legendary can drop at level 70. The fact that you got multiple Fire Walkers and no Ice Climbers is just based on luck (on a random number generator actually, but that resulst basically in luck).

As proof: At the time of this post [this](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/profile/BlackheiM-1957/hero/1592602) character is wearing lvl 70 Ice Climbers. Or just look at the screenshot I found of them

[image: Ice Climbers]

Comment: They definitely exist. I keep getting them instead of lut socks, very annoying. I doubt ones with 900+ main stat still exist though, I believe 500 is the max main stat now. At least from the ones I've gotten.  And movement speed is now considered a primary stat, not secondary.

Comment: It's some picture I found on google, it's fuzzy and seemeingly old-ish. If you have a better picture, please edit it in :)